# Windows Dual NIC - Will this setup cause an ip address conflict?

Tags: networking, routing, nic, ip-address

[image]

My company has three subnets total of which two subnets have the same set of ip addresses...  192.168.0.x.  This has not been an issue before but we are going to establish a VPN connection between two routers.  So now my network will look like the above diagram.

Client A is a standard windows desktop box with two nics installed.  Windows default settings.  No bridging.  Here is how I would like each machine to function...

Client A --> 192.168.0.70 --> Client C

Client B --> 192.168.0.70 --> Client D

My understanding is that by default windows routes outgoing traffic according to each NIC's ip address.  If so after I establish the VPN the routing should be functioning as descried correct?  If not what can I do to get that functionality?

P.S.

I do realize the ideal thing to do would be changing one of my 192.168.0.x subnets to something else.  For reasons outside my control this is not an option.

Comment: I'm not understanding your question or your diagram. On the right side of your diagram you have computers with ip addresses from both subnets. That can't possibly work.

Comment: There are three subnets total.  Does the edit clear it up for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/548888/connecting-to-a-remote-server-through-a-vpn-when-the-local-network-subnet-addres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***This is a bad idea.***

Ok, that being said, as long as Client D will never, ever need to get to anythng on Client C or it's subnet this might work. Client A should have it's default gateway set on the NIC in the 192.168.111.0 subnet, and the NIC on the 192.168.0.0 subnet **MUST NOT HAVE** a default gateway set.  Or your packets will be very confused as to where to go.

I cannot stress enough how bad of an idea this is.  Especially if there is going to be more than one machine configured like Client A.

Comment: Yes needless to say I am unhappy with this setup.  I have two OEMs for industrial equipment claiming that the IP addresses are hard-coded and can't be changed.  The manufacturing machines I'm working with are amazing from a mechanical standpoint but they don't have anything close to best practices when it comes to networking.

Comment: I've had my fair share of dealings with industrial computing issues.  My sympathies.